# Dynamically specify Header attribute name in XHR request

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am creating xhr call argumnets:

```
var CUSTOM_HEADER = "XAppName";
.
.
var xhrArgs = {
url: "../../rest/getCustomerData,
postData: dojo.toJson(custJSONObj),
handleAs: "json",
headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept" : "application/json","REMOTE_USER" : "admin", CUSTOM_HEADER: "abc"}
}
```

When I am posting this request, in the request header, CUSTOM_HEADER is shown as request header attribute instead of "XAppName".

How to dynamically set the header attribute name in the above scenario.
I want to do it inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try instead

```
 var xhrArgs = {
    ...
    headers : { 
       "Content-Type": "application/json", 
       "Accept" : "application/json",
       "REMOTE_USER" : "admin"
    }
 };

 xhrArgs['headers'][CUSTOM_HEADER] = "abc";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is there any way to do it inline. Here headers inside  another object.

Comment: Its working like a charm. Thanks a lot. But still wondering is there any way by which I can set this dynamic attribute in the same line where headers is defined?